# Importing data time changed to Date on import

Tags: matlab, import

I have a text file that I want to import into Matlab using the import data tool. 
The original format of one line is:-

> 20150904 060004 .... ..... .....

Matlab has 200150904 in the first column, which I have set the formatting to yyyyMMDD and that works fine. For the second column, 060004, I have set the formatting to HHmmss but when the date is imported it changes it to a date format and is displaying 07-Sep-2015 for that cell?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. My "Import Data..." tool has no way of specifying that these are dates (it just imports the numbers). What version of MATLAB do you have?

Comment: The case of the format specifier is reversed. The lower case `m` is for month and the upper case `M` is for minutes. So your formats should be: `yyyymmdd` and `HHMMSS`. See the [format specifier](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_formatOut) documentation for date strings.

Comment: @CST im using Version R2015a and the in the import data tool you can specify the data type and the format.  at Hoki  I looked at the format specifier and its says mm for Mins and MM for months.

Answer (score 0):

This soltuion has to be fitted to the type of your input but lets say each colum is a cell, then this would work:

```
X=[{'20150904'} {'060004'};...
{'20150904'} {'070004'};...
{'20150904'} {'080004'}];; % as example if the input happen to be a cell array

Y=datetime(cell2mat(X) ,'InputFormat','yyyyMMddhhmmss','Format','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS')%the 'Format' Parameter determines how the date is visualized for you
```